# Styling the relevant input on validation error, like MVC

Tags: asp.net

I have search the net and not found anything that has helped, so thought I would ask on here.

I have a simple asp.net 2.0 form.

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />

    <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="valGroup1"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txt1" ValidationGroup="valGroup1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ID="val1" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="valGroup1" CausesValidation="true" Text="submit" />
</form>
```

What I want to do is to change the styling on the input when validation fails for that particular input. Preferably by adding a class, not inline styles.

I can do this when javascript is not available via code behind, but what I want to do is have the same happen when javascript is available.

I know that ASP.NET injects a global js variable called Page_Validators, which is an array of all of the validator spans on the page. Is there an easier way to do this other than looping through all of these??

***EDIT***

I can sort of do it with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function ValidateInputs() {

            var validators = Page_Validators;

            for (var i = 0; i < validators.length; i++) {
                var validator = validators[i];
                if (!validator.isvalid) {
                    document.getElementById(validator.controltovalidate).setAttribute("style", "border:solid 1px red;");
                }
            }

        }

    </script>
```

Was just wondering if there was a better way??

And can I get the microwoft validation scripts to call my validation method? or can I hook into the validation event manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my answer is the only one that I am going to get!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function ValidateInputs() {


            Page_ClientValidate();//Validate the validators using microsofts validation

            var validators = Page_Validators;

            for (var i = 0; i < validators.length; i++) {
                var validator = validators[i];
                if (!validator.isvalid) {
                    document.getElementById(validator.controltovalidate).setAttribute("style", "border:solid 1px red;");
                }
            }

        }

    </script>
```

Also, on the button, set the `OnClientClick="ValidateInputs();"` to `OnClientClick="ValidateInputs();return false;"`

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty good way of doing it; there is no public event or something else to tap into, unless you want to start replacing public events with your own custom ones (that gets messy).

HTH.

Comment: Thanks Brian. As I have never done this, was just trying to tap the geniuses out there that might know if there is a better way. I guess this solution could work, although I have to change the way I call the validation event, at the moment I have it going off of onclick, which is fired before the validators are there to crawl as the page has returned it's validation response. :(

Comment: Maybe you could tap into form.onsubmit for display purposes.  I don't think there is a generic event, unless you replace the Page_Validate method with a custom implementation that includes your logic.